# Automatically remove part of a .cfm file

Tags: windows-7, pdf

I'm looking to chop off (or crop) part of the left side of a .cfm.  I'll need to do this hundreds of times.  Is there a faster way?

Eventually I'll need them in a PDF, but I think that needs to be done a completely different way

Comment: cold fusion markup file? can you be a bit more descriptive as to what you need done? It might be something you can put into a batch file or vbscript, even the pdf portion, but we'll need a better understanding of what you mean by "chop off (or crop)"

Comment: By .cfm I mean a website like [this](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/Class/vectors/u3l3a.cfm)

Comment: So will you be pulling off the web? or a local file?

Comment: they're the same to me.  I can download the .cfm(s) instantly, but can you web method penetrate an entire web site? (physicsclassroom.com/class and physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors...)

Comment: @MaQleod  Please post an answer, I'm looking to give someone some rep.